# How to set documentLaunchMode that "sticks together" (like what Chrome does) in overview?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-5.0-lollipop

I noticed that when I open a new tab from Chrome ("Merge tabs and apps" enabled), the new tabs from same domain will stick together in Overview.

The code like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, SomeActivity.class)
            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(i);
```

or setting `android:documentLaunchMode="always"` in `AndroidManifest.xml` can open multiple cards but not "stick together" (like what Chrome does) in overview.

Answer (score 1):

After 7 months my friend @mthli finally found the solution:

```
startActivity(newDocumentIntent,
    ActivityOptions.makeTaskLaunchBehind().toBundle());
```

[image: screenshot]

Original link (Chinese): https://www.zhihu.com/question/34100283/answer/85058405